# Twitter bootstrap: Input fields taking up too much space when page size is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/R5TB2/

```
code is in the fiddle :)
```

Whenever the page size gets reduced so that the input fields get put below the labels, the input fields get immensly large! I might have some serious bootstrap knowledge gaps here, but I can't, for the life of me, see what's causing this!

Any suggestions? I've tried all the margin: 0 auto etc., and it didn't work. And I'd like to get this to work without any 'hacks' ^^

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/R5TB2/1/

You have to change the BT class :

`col-md-*` to `col-xs-*`

**Extract :**
Change

```
<label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username.." />
    </div>
```

to

```
<label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username.." />
    </div>
```

**Here is the doc :** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT**

Look this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9URh5/

You can add class for each devise

**UPDATE AGAIN :**

When you resize windows, look this native class :

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.form-horizontal .control-label {
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now that that problem is solved, I see there are more problems to my code! At some point the text fields gets a bit smaller for (apparently?) no reason (maybe cus the column size is auto in xs, and they can't exceed that? But how can I work around that?), and when the size gets REALLY small the labels jump all the way to the left. Is that .control-label's fault? Thanks again :)

Comment: Look my update, you can add multiple class : col-xs-2 col-sm-4, and change width of navigator

Comment: Hm ok, but that doesn't really answer my questions.

Comment: Oups sorry I answer to you : In updating again ^^ Ok, so that's the reason about the right-left alignment. [sorry i need to go home]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on how bootstrap grid layout works.

Your problem is this, `col-md-5`

As soon as your screen is below this `md` size, the bootstrap class doesn't apply, and thus the width resorts to it's default size, auto, which stretches it to fit it's parent container.

You should be using `xs`